# Can a smooth convex functions be non-differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, locally-convex-spaces

Consider the definition of the $\beta$-smoothness (for some constant $\beta$): 
$$
\|\left. \nabla f \right|_{ y } - \left. \nabla f \right|_{ x }  \| \leq \beta \| x - y \| 
$$
And convexity: 
$$
f(x) \geq f(y)+  \left. \nabla f \right|_{ y } . (x - y), \forall x, y
$$
Can a smooth convex function be non-differentiable at some points on its domain? (and why?)

In the definitions, $\left. \nabla f \right|_{y}$ is subgradient of the function $f$ at point $y$, if it is not differentiable at this point; so the definitions of convexity and smoothness hold even for non-differentiable functions.

Comment: This definition seems to implicitly assume that $ f$ is differentiable, otherwise what does $\nabla f $ mean?

Comment: Ah I see. For this definition, let's assume this definition holds for any sub-gradient.

Comment: That's an odd definition of smoothness... According to it $f(x) = x^2$ is not smooth. Where does this definition come from?

Comment: Updated it with parameter $\beta$. This is mostly used in convex analysis. For example see page 18 of http://ocobook.cs.princeton.edu/OCObook.pdf (mid-page equation)

Comment: Ill-stated question. Nothing to do.

Comment: What part of the question is unclear, @dohmatob?

Comment: I think that the definition of $\beta$-smoothness given here currently (after edits) disagrees with the definition given on p. 18 of the textbook; the textbook definition actually assumes that $f$ is differentiable, so $\nabla f$ is truly a gradient and not just a subgradient.  For future readers of this question, I think we should clarify that this isn't the standard definition of $\beta$-smooth.

Comment: The reference material just says: a function is $\beta$-smooth if $f(y) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y - x) + \frac{\beta}{2} \| y - x \|^2$.

Comment: I updated the definition of smoothness (although these two definition are essentially equivalent). Does it look any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convex function $f$ is non-differentiable at a point $x$ iff the subgradient $\nabla f|_x$ has more than one vector.  I presume the inequality
$\|\nabla f|_x - \nabla f|_y\| \le \beta \|x - y \|$  means 
$\|v - w\| \le \beta \|x - y\|$ for **all** $v \in \nabla f|_x$ and $w \in \nabla f|_y$.  In particular, for $y = x$ you see that $\nabla f|_x$ must contain only one vector for this to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the definition of smooth-ness you are using is something specific to convex functions. Its not the standard definition of a function that a function is continuously differentiable and has derivatives of all orders C∞;

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness although I note that you are using a particular definition here.

I note that discrete analogues involving subgradients and the like are also used in characterizing (not necessarily diff-erentiable, in the traditional sense) 'pseudo convex functions' using more discrete notion such as the "dini 'derivative" see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative